# Arduino or c++ working with array in parameter of function

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  printArr([64,67]);
}

void loop() {}

void printArr(byte nilai[]) {
  for (byte c = 0; c < length(nilai); c++) {
    Serial.println(nilai[c]);
  }
}
```

I expect the program print char of number 64 and 67 in ASCII since it was iterated in array, but instead the compiler give me error

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\sketch_apr18a\sketch_apr18a.ino:10:24: note: suggested alternative: 'long'
   for (byte c = 0; c < length(nilai); c++) {
                        ^~~~~~
                        long
exit status 1
expected identifier before numeric constant
```

Comment: You can't pass an array literal. And `length` is probably not defined.

Comment: @lurker I change ```length``` with ```sizeof()``` and it gave me ```C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\sketch_apr18a\sketch_apr18a.ino: In function 'void setup()':
sketch_apr18a:3:19: error: expected ')' before ']' token
   printArr([64, 67]);
                   ^
exit status 1
expected identifier before numeric constant
```

Comment: Yup. That's what the first part of my last comment was about. Define a variable holding the array literal and pass the variable.

Comment: Okay it works, but i need to make new parameter for size of array. Is there other way how to make array as input without holding variable, im afraid if it holds it will make memory smaller

Comment: If it's a local variable in your setup function (as shown in the posted answer) it will be allocated on the stack and will be freed when setup exits.

Answer (score 0):

A solving can be:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  byte arr [] = {64,67};
  printArr(arr, 2);
}

void loop() {}

void printArr(byte *nylai, unsigned d) {
  for (byte c = 0; c < d; c++) {
    Serial.println(*(nylai + c * sizeof(byte)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Better: `const byte arr [] ...` Also use `const` for the function argument.